# R: Update model by changing modeling function

Tags: r, function, updates, updatemodel

I have a `gls` model in R. I want to update it in two ways:

1. Adding predictors
2. **Changing the function from `gls` to `lm`.**

The `update()` function obviously works just fine with #1, but **is there a way to update a model to change the fitting function itself???**

For example: 
I want to change `gls(y ~ x)` to `lm(y ~ x + z)`.

Note: 
The `update` approach is necessary b/c this process is going into a function that will have greatly different input models, so simply copying the model arguments seems difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not using any current form of the `update` function.  This will require some more advanced programming and therefore is probably not for the new user of R.

If you are comfortable with programming in R and some of the internals then read on, otherwise you may need to consult/hire an R programmer to help.

You can see what the `update` function does by looking at the code for `update.default`.  But that only changes the options and formula, not the actual function that will be called.  Looking at the first part of the code to `lm` you can see an example of changing the calling function when lm uses `match.call` to get the `lm` call, then changes the first element to `model.fram` and then calls `eval` on that.  You will need to write your own `update` function (call it something else so there is no confusion) that does the same thing as `lm` to change from `gls` to `lm` and then do the same thing as `update.default` to change the formula to add the additional predictor.  then `eval` the result and you have the basics of what you want.

Comment: Good thing I've been using R for 5 years. Could you clarify what you mean by "to change from gls to lm and then do the same thing as update.default". That whole sentence is not clear to me what/where you're modifying. Thanks!

Comment: @theforestecologist, Look at the first part of the code for the `lm` function.  It uses `match.call` to save a copy of the call, then changes the 1st element of that call to `model.frame`.  You need to do the same thing, only using `getCall` like `update` does and changing from a `gls` call to `lm`.  Then you can modify the formula.